# Partitioned table - insert directly or create a staging table first and switch in?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is it the same regarding to the performance (or the difference can be neglected)? The data to be inserted are all in the new partition.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on current load on the table, indexes on it - (if exists index, which is not partitioned, can cause problems). Actually - depends. Try on your test simulating load environment.

**Current load influences:**

It may be negligible, or not, need to test, but if table under high insert/update/read load, then inserting data row by row into the table will cause to big amount of short-time locks, but overall wait time may be significant. So - switching partition can significantly reduce overall locking time, since you have no indexes other than clustered

Also this can cause to deadlocks when you'll try to read subset of data with filter other than clustered index/primary key (since you have no any indexes on table except clustered) - this will cause to clustered index scan and if there will be an inserted/updated record during this scan - it may cause deadlock.

Comment: Right now there is no non-clustered index. It will be partitioned if needed. Could you elaborate the impact of _current load_?